# How to bind Listview to Observablecollection in a static class of another namespace

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, static, namespaces

I reed a lot about namespace but still facing a problem / misunderstanding.

I would like to bind a Listview to an Observablecollection which resides in a static class in another namespace. It works but I can't succeed without code. I'm sure there is a better way to do this entirely in the XAML file.

So, this is my XAML file (...a part of - I delete a lot to be clear ...) :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ToolBox"
             x:Class="ToolBox.MainPage">
    
    <StackLayout>
        
        <ListView x:Name="listToolBox">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell   Text="{Binding  Name}"
                                Detail="{Binding CreateDate}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        
    </StackLayout>
```

I set up the binding context of the "listToolBox" in the code behind:

```
...
using ToolBox.Model;

namespace ToolBox
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listToolBox.ItemsSource = ToolBox.Model.EBis.ToolBoxList;
        }
        ...
```

It refers to a member of a static class:

```
namespace ToolBox.Model
{

    public static class EBis
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<cDocuments> ToolBoxList = new ObservableCollection<cDocuments>
        {
            new cDocuments{ Id = -1, Name = "Pas (encore) de connection aux serveurs ..."}
        };
    ...
```

MY QUESTION:
What are the binding instructions I have to write in the XAML elements in order to delete this line of code behind

```
listToolBox.ItemsSource = ToolBox.Model.EBis.ToolBoxList;
```

To be complete, the structure of my "Toolbox" APP is here:
[image: see solution explorer]

Thanks a lot for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the x:Static markup extension:

```
<ListView ItemsSource=“{x:Static local:Model.EBis.ToolBoxList}”>
```